# LinkedIn API shows decrease in visitors demographics lifetime values #linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I am making requests for **lifetime** page statistics in LinkedIn API organizationPageStatistics endpoint following the instructions from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/page-statistics?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http). They return (among other stats) page views segmented by some demographic facets. Watching the results on a daily basis, sometimes there is a decrease in those values.

Does anyone know how to interpret this drop in a lifetime values?

---

Sample responses to better illustrate this situation. I am focusing on the metric allPageViews for a single facet to make my point more clear.

Lets say on June 1st request to `GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization={organization URN}` returns.

```
"pageStatisticsByCountry": [
                {
                    "country": "urn:li:country:us",
                    "pageStatistics": {
                        "views": {
                            "allPageViews": {
                                "pageViews": 1696
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

On June 2nd the same request returns

```
"pageStatisticsByCountry": [
                {
                    "country": "urn:li:country:us",
                    "pageStatistics": {
                        "views": {
                            "allPageViews": {
                                "pageViews": 1691
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

How is it possible that there are -5 views from June 1st to June 2nd?

#linkedin